# How to change the lineSpacing of NSTextView?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextview

I have searched some pages. And I found the answer code like the below...

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *para = [[[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy] autorelease]; 

[para setLineSpacing:message.defaultParagraphStyle.lineSpacing + (float)2.5];

[message setDefaultParagraphStyle:(NSParagraphStyle*)para];
```

But it seems it didn't work. Any idea or any wrong usage here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will do it:

```
CGFloat spacing = 55.0f;
NSMutableParagraphStyle *para =[[[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy] autorelease];
[para setLineSpacing:spacing];
[para setMinimumLineHeight:spacing];
[para setMaximumLineHeight:spacing];
[yourTextView setDefaultParagraphStyle:para];

NSString *stringWithLineBreak = @"test \n test text \n more test text \n";
[yourTextView setString:stringWithLineBreak];
```

Comment: wired. If I don't add [yourTextView setString:stringWithLineBreak]; it will not act on the spacing. But I got it works by setting it to null again. Thanks!